# Generating a PDF using Wicked PDF with Google Charts and JvectorMap not rendering Maps and Charts in the PDF

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf, jvectormap

I'm using [Wicked PDF](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)  to generate a report which shows a Map generated by jvectormap and a Bar Chart that is generated with Google Charts.

I'm using this two gems 'wicked_pdf' and 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'.
I have set a JavaScript delay on the respond_to Method of 50000m and on the initializers we have specified the path of the needed wicked gems.
And then I'm using a pdf_layout.html.erb where we set the pdf generation.

Here are the files I'm talking about:
Gemfile:

```
Gemfile
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge'
```

Controller: respond_to format

```
format.pdf do
        @is_pdf = true
        pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string("reports/show.html.erb",
                                                              encoding: "UTF-8",
                                                              layout: "reports/layout_pdf.html.erb",
                                                              page_size: "Letter",
                                                              margin:  {  bottom:            0,
                                                                          top:               0,
                                                                          left:              0,
                                                                          right:             0,  },
                                                              javascript_delay: 50000,
                                            ))
        send_data pdf, :filename => "resume.pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
      end
```

The PDF Layout:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>PDF Generation</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'report' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdfreport' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'ionicons' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'font-awesome' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'import-bootstrap' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'jquery-jvectormap' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'jquery-jvectormap-world-mill' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'jquery-jvectormap-world-en' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'market_map' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'number_pages' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'highcharts' %>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js' %>

  </head>
  <body onload="number_pages">
    <div id="content">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The map and the charts are showing in the HTML online view but not when you generate the pdf.

I've tried everything from every related answer here in Stack Overflow and the Issues in the gem but no luck.